# Clipping ROI in TerraClimate - Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, clip, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to analyze a polygon that I imported from Google Earth and get images for that polygon only. How can I do that? I tried clipping the area but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
// Load the TerraClimate image collection and filter it by a date range
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('1979-01', '2016-01'));

// Load the region of interest 
var subwatershed = ee.FeatureCollection('users/cherratc/subwatershed-polygon');
subwatershed = subwatershed.geometry();

**//Clip the region of interest 
var clipToCol = function(image){
  return image.clip(subwatershed);
};**
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a few things. (1) To clip over an ImageCollection, you need to use the map function; (2) your function was written incorrectly. I reproduced your code using an arbitrary geometry. Hope this helps!

```
// Load the region of interest 
var geometry = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[102.7313828161343, 15.766103402947243],
          [102.7973007848843, 15.045882564876912],
          [103.6762070348843, 15.469844390172305],
          [103.2367539098843, 15.935200835257389]]]);
Map.centerObject(geometry)

// Load the TerraClimate image collection and filter it by a date range 
var test = ee.ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE")
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('1979-01-01', '2016-01-31'))
  .map(clipToCol);
  
Map.addLayer(test);

//Clip the region of interest 
function clipToCol(image) { 
  return image.clip(geometry); 
}
```